# Match div to window size with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element which drops down when I toggle my menu bars.
I can make the element as large or as small as I like but can't make it fit to screen so it doesn't scroll and no page shows underneath. It's a WordPress site and I started off with an an i class `fa-bars`. It wasn't possible to animate font awesome so I replaced it with this.

```html
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs">
    <a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
        <div class="container1"
             onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <script>
        function myFunction(x) {
            x.classList.toggle('change');
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

This worked to toggle the menu amd make it drop but it didn't cover the screen. The element controlling the dropdown area was too small so I enlarged it by increasing height, like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .collapse {
        position: absolute;
        height: 775px;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 99999 !important;
        top: 75px;
        left: -50px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }
}
```

This made it too high but making it any lower would show the page underneath.

Is there a way I can modify my existing javascript or css to make it fit to screen exactly, responsively with no scroll and no page showing underneath?

It's located in my header.php so it would go there I'm assuming, if there's a way to modify what i already have. If not, what's a good way to approach this?

[here on mobile](https://4309.co.uk)

Html dropdown.

```html
<div class="module-group right">
    <div class="module left">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul id="menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-15050"
                    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-15050 dropdown">
                    <a title="Contact" href="url">Contact
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdow n-menu">
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried applying `min-height` to element `collapse` `max- height` and  `100%`  None worked.

Here's a pen https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/bGVXNVM

Comment: You could use `vh`. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: I could and it would change height but wouldn't work to match height of device and not scroll or show page underneath. Already tried. Good idea though.

Comment: If you want to prevent the scroll of the page, you should add `overflow: hidden` to your body. Or you could use `position: fixed` for the menu. In any case, the menu should also have `overflow: auto` in case the menu is bigger than the viewport.

Comment: Basically its good now but the page is scrolling at the top when i open the menu here https://4309.co.uk/services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `position: fixed` to size the element with respect to the frame:

```
.your-selector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This will make it take up the entire window. It's not clear if you're wanting it to cover the window *in all dimensions*, but you can choose where the top/bottom/left/right anchor selectively.

If you're also wanting to make the body (or if it's not the body some other scrollable element) non-scrollable, set the `overflow` style to `hidden`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214968/discussion-on-answer-by-jacob-match-div-to-window-size-with-css-or-javascript).